# Reducing Wasm filesize (libc, optimization, emscripten)

Tags: c++, optimization, emscripten, webassembly

So, I did a lot of experimentation with Emscripten. And what I noticed pretty much is that the musl-libc that is being used is impressively huge...like, *really* huge. A simple "Hello, World!" printing app is way above the 10kb...which is by far not practical.

Now how can I reduce this? So far, I figured that I could use `-Os` and `--closure 1`. But the latter only really works over JavaScript, so it does not affect the Wasm output.

What else can I do? Use a different libc implementation, maybe? I looked at uClibc and dietlibc as well as Metallic. I also thought about looing for a cheap - filesize-wise - deflate function so I could transfer a gzipped version of the Wasm binary. But so far, that is all I got.

Any suggestions? My last try was:

```
emcc test.cpp -o test.wasm -s WASM=1 -Os --closure 1
```

where `test.cpp` is just a `printf("Hello, world");`.

Comment: You could try with -Oz too, but Emscripten is maybe not the good toolset to target embedded systems. It is a toolset to target web browsers for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple answer: If you care about the binary size, never use `printf()`, consider using `puts()`.

In my experiment, `printf()` version of "Hello world" is whopping 13KB, and `puts()` version is as small as 2KB.

You say "`A simple "Hello, World!" printing app`", but it is actually not true in the wider perspective because **`printf()` is by far the biggest part of the C standard library in terms of the binary size**. Actually I am a bit surprised that they managed reducing it to 13KB. This is mainly because of the `%` formatting. Not only `printf()` deals with simple formats such as `%c`, `%d`, and `%ld`, but it has to deal with complex formats such as `%4.2f`, `%+.0e`, `%E`, and `%*d`.

Apart from the web application, this is a common problem in the embedded systems where you should statically link against stdlib and the available program memory size is often as small as 10kb. [Just google "printf size in embedded system"](https://www.google.com/search?q=printf+size+in+embedded+system), you will easily see a lot of hates around printf() and a lot of efforts to reduce size of it.

Switching stdlib like uClibc and dietlibc won't help much because they still are libraries for the POSIX system which implements a full specification of printf(). You should look for stdlibs for bare-metal embedded systems such as newlib-nano that implements a subset of printf() specification to reduce the binary size. Moreover, I don't think switching stdlib for Emscripten is almost an impossible job because Emscripten uses significantly hacked version of musl-libc for their use case.

Comment: Another solution along the same lines is real C++; use `std::cout`. It too doesn't do run-time formatting, which means you need only those `operator<<` overloads that you actually used, and the logic to choose them has already run in the compiler.

Comment: @MSalters That is interesting. I'm a C embedded system dev who recently plays around Emscripten. I didn't know much about C++ IO. I will add about `std::cout` after a short studying.

Comment: @MSalters Well I tried `std::cout << "Hello World"` but the binary size is amazing 150KB so it can't be a solution for Emscripten. I think `iostream` needs a big size of runtime.

Comment: Thanks @BumsikKim and @MSalters! I have to admit, I completely did not think about the formating capabilities that `printf` has - no surprise it ends up this big. I will experiment with `std::cout` and see what happens with it. Besides - it may not do formatting, but due to operator overloading, some value types can still easily be printed, be it with less formatting...which is not what I want to do anyway. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BumsikKim I can confirm: 192kb with `cout`, `endl` and `string`. Ouch! Even running `wasm-gc` over it doesn't do anything good to reduce that size. Well...with that, this particular part of STL goes totally out of the choice. All those operator overloadings may not have been stripped...i wish there was `nm` for reading symbols in WASM files. x) Thank you anyway!